# Crawl Multiple pages from a website (BeautifulSoup,Requests,Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, request, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm wondering how to crawl multiple different pages from one website using beautiful soup/requests without having to repeat my code over and over.

In the following my current code, which is crawling the tourist attraction of certain cities:

```
RegionIDArray = [187147,187323,186338]
dict = {187147: 'Paris', 187323: 'Berlin', 186338: 'London'}
already_printed = set()

for reg in RegionIDArray:
    for page in range(1,700,30):
        r = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.de/Attractions-c47-g" + str(reg) + "-oa" + str(page) + ".html")

        g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "element_wrap"})

        for item in g_data:
            header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "property_title"})
            item = (header[0].text.strip())
            if item not in already_printed:
                already_printed.add(item)

                print("POI: " + str(item) + " | " + "Location: " + str(dict[reg]) + " | " + "Art: Museum ")
```

So far everything works as expected. In the next step I would like to crawl the most popular museums of these cities, in addition to the tourist attractions.

Hence, I have to modify the request by changing the c parameter, in order to get all the required museums:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.de/Attractions-c" + str(museumIDArray) +"-g" + str(reg) + "-oa" + str(page) + ".html")
```

Therefore my code would look like this:

```
RegionIDArray = [187147,187323,186338]
museumIDArray = [47,49]
dict = {187147: 'Paris', 187323: 'Berlin', 186338: 'London'}
already_printed = set()

for reg in RegionIDArray:
    for page in range(1,700,30):
        r = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.de/Attractions-c" + str(museumIDArray) +"-g" + str(reg) + "-oa" + str(page) + ".html")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

        g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "element_wrap"})

        for item in g_data:
            header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "property_title"})
            item = (header[0].text.strip())
            if item not in already_printed:
                already_printed.add(item)

                print("POI: " + str(item) + " | " + "Location: " + str(dict[reg]) + " | " + "Art: Museum ")
```

That does not seem exactly right. The output that I get, does not include all museums and tourist attractions of certain cities.

Can anyone help me with that? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Your code would error, also what is dict doing in your code bar shadowing a python builtin?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What do you mean with " shadowing a python builtin" Sorry, If I´m getting on your nerves but I´m still a beginner

Comment: dict is a python type/function, it is best to avoid shadowing i.e using the same names for vriables as builtin types. Can you add a link and explain exactly what you want to parse from it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham this is the link: https://www.tripadvisor.de/Attractions-c49-g187147-Activities-Paris_Ile_de_France.html  From this link I would like to parse the header from the respective items, like Musée d'Orsay or Louvre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the names are in the anchor tags inside the divs with the `property_title` class.

```
for reg in RegionIDArray:
    for page in range(1,700,30):
        r = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.de/Attractions-c" + str(museumIDArray) +"-g" + str(reg) + "-oa" + str(page) + ".html")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

        for item in (a.text for a in soup.select("div.property_title a")):
            if item not in already_printed:
                already_printed.add(item)
                print("POI: " + str(item) + " | " + "Location: " + str(dct[reg]) + " | " + "Art: Museum ")
```

It is also better to get the links from the pagination div:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import  urljoin


RegionIDArray = [187147,187323,186338]
museumIDArray = [47,49]
dct = {187147: 'Paris', 187323: 'Berlin', 186338: 'London'}
already_printed = set()

def get_names(soup):
    for item in (a.text for a in soup.select("div.property_title a")):
        if item not in already_printed:
            already_printed.add(item)
            print("POI: {} | Location: {} | Art: Museum ".format(item, dct[reg]))

base = "https://www.tripadvisor.de"
for reg in RegionIDArray:
    r = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.de/Attractions-c[47,49]-g{}-oa.html".format(reg))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    # get links to all next pages.
    all_pages = (urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in soup.select("div.unified.pagination a.pageNum.taLnk")[1:])
    # use helper function to print the names.
    get_names(soup)

    # visit all remaining pages.
    for url in all_pages:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
        get_names(soup)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. But now I´m getting the follwoing error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Raju/Desktop/Scripts/nnnn.py", line 25, in <module>
    get_names(soup)
  File "C:/Users/Raju/Desktop/Scripts/nnnn.py", line 15, in get_names
    print("POI: {} | Location: {} | " + "Art: Museum ".format(item. dict[reg]))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dict'                                                                                                          Could you help me out? What is wrong?

Comment: @SeriousRuffy,  you were using dict?

Comment: @Padriac It should be dct, like your stated in your code above. I just tried with "dict". Nevertheless, I get the same error message

Comment: @SeriousRuffy, had a period where there should have been a comma, t should run fine now